# NameD = request.form('Name') TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable

Tags: python, android, flask, okhttp

I wanted to pass these values to my Flask and receive a response.
This how I build my FormBody and request and method to revive its response:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
RequestBody formBody;
Request request;

okHttpClient= new OkHttpClient();
formBody=new FormBody.Builder().add("Name",Date_Time).add("Humidity_value",hum).build();

request=new Request.Builder().url("http://10.0.2.2:5000/api").post(formBody).build();

okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
 @Override
 public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                Log.d("message","Network not found");
            }

 @Override
 public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.d("message",response.body().string());
            }
        });
```

I put the dependencies and and import the required libraries, but I get error said in Android Studio:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
    <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
    <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
    <p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

and another error in my flask side:

```
Name = request.form('Name')
TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2021 15:12:01] "POST /api HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Here is my flask code:

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    NameD = request.form('Name') **#the console said the error is here**
    NameD = pd.to_datetime(NameD).value
    NameD = float(NameD)
    Humidity_value = request.form('Humidity_value')
   
    
    inputs = np.array([[NameD,Humidity_value]])

    prediction = model.predict(inputs)
    output = prediction[0]
    
    return (str(output))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

how can I solve the `TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable` error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.form` is an `ImmutableMultiDict` which is similar to python dictionary, you cannot use `round brackets ()` for retrieving data from the form. Instead use `square brackets []`. Change all your instances of `request.form('key')` to `request.form['key']`. Or you can use `request.form.get('key')`.

Using round brackets () here is similar as trying to call a function. As we cannot call a `ImmutableMultiDict`, the error occurs. The error inside the android studio most probably occured because of the error in the flask script.

Your predict function should be

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    NameD = request.form['Name']
    NameD = pd.to_datetime(NameD).value
    NameD = float(NameD)
    Humidity_value = request.form['Humidity_value']
    Light_Sensor_Reading = request.form['Light_Sensor_Reading']
    Smoke_Detection = request.form['Smoke_Detection']
    Temperature_value = request.form['Temperature_value']
    Door_status = request.form['Door_status']
    
    inputs = np.array([[NameD,Humidity_value,Light_Sensor_Reading,Smoke_Detection,Temperature_value,Door_status]])

    prediction = model.predict(inputs)
    output = prediction[0]
    
    return (str(output))
```

Comment: Just a small tip, you can use `request.form.get('Name')` too, this will return `None` if the specified key does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @vremes. I had already included it in the solution.